# Retrieving Images from a folder- ajax code not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my project in mvc4. I have an Image folder and I want to open and list all images in that folder using jquery . I write the following jquery ajax code for that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var URL = "../Home/Show?foldername=DGInstallation";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        success: function (data) {                
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function () {
                var images = $(this).attr("href");   
                alert(images);   //i want to get the particular image name, but this  is not working
            });
        }

    });       
});
```

here data contains the whole html file and I am trying to retrieve the jpg images

```
<div id="galcontent">
   <p style="padding:15px 10px 0 10px;"><a href="/Home/Gallery" style="text-decoration:underline;color:red;">Back to Gallery</a></p>
   <a href="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/afdgfd.jpg" rel="lightbox" data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <div class="thumb">
      <img src="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/afdgfd.jpg" /></div></a>
   <a href="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/gfdfutr.jpg" rel="lightbox" data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <div class="thumb">
      <img src="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/gfdfutr.jpg" /></div></a>
   <a href="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/gffg.jpg" rel="lightbox" data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <div class="thumb">
      <img src="/Content/Gallery/GalleryImages/DGInstallation/gffg.jpg" /></div></a>
 </div>
```

these are the image and how I retrieve the names

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code I have created sample fiddle for you have a look here :-

```
$("#galcontent").find('a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function () { 
                var images = $(this).attr("href");   
                alert(images);   //i want to get the particular image name, but this  is not working
            });
```

**Demo** :-

http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/30/